# Show wireframe with solid shading in edit mode

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode, wireframe

In video at ArtStation the teacher uses the screw modifier, then he goes into edit mode and the generated geometry wireframe still shows:

[image: Edit Mode with wireframe]

https://www.artstation.com/learning/courses/OzX/introduction-concepting-in-blender/chapters/9eJ8/boolean-practice-handguard

I have **wireframe** enabled under **viewport overlays** and see the wireframe (with **solid viewport shading**) in **object mode**:
[image: Object Mode]

However in **edit mode** I only get this:
[image: Edit Mode]

Under **object properties** / **viewport display** I also tried enabling **wireframe** (which seems to do the same as **wireframe** setting under **viewport overlays**, just per object) and **all edges**, but that did not help. I'm using a later version than the teacher, was this functionality removed? I cannot find any option to turn it on. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, that's strange, it seems screw generated geometry does not show wires in wireframe mode (before the modifier is applied). I can not find a way to get it to display. Could you take a screenshot of the moment he activates it in the video? - The video you linked is locked for those who do not have an account.

Comment: I just added screenshot from video showing him in edit mode with wireframe showing, 
but it was screenshotted from my phone, not the best quality.

Comment: Can confirm  that it seems to work like described in older versions (I tried a fresh install 2.93, the one in the video is 3.1.2), but not in newer ones. Couldn't find a patch where the change happens though, so maybe it's a bug? Not sure. Could ask the devs after holidays if no one comes with an answer I guess.

Comment: Earliest version it stops working seems to be 3.4, when the *Viewer Node* option was added to the overlays, I'm assuming that's the culprit.